# Springboot save registration form with image altogether

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am struggling about  6 days to create a registration form using spring rest API that will save a patient's data with image. I tried every possible way and failed every time. All I need is your support.  I wanted to use @ModelAttribute, not RequestParam. Could anyone please help me?

This is the Entity class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table (name = "patient_registration")
public class PatientRegistrationEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String patientName; 
    private String salutation; 
    private String age;
    private String patientPhone; 
    private String patientAddress; 
    private String gender;
    private String religion;
    private String dateOfBirth; 
    private String marritalStatus; 
    private String fatherName; 
    private String motherName;
    
//  private byte [] patientImage;

    @Lob
    private String patientImage;
}
```

This is repository interace

```
public interface PatientRegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<PatientRegistrationEntity, Integer> {}
```

This is the service class

```
@Service
public class PatientRegistrationService {
    
    @Autowired
    private PatientRegistrationRepository repository;
    
    public List<PatientRegistrationEntity>getPatientList(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    
    public PatientRegistrationEntity createPatient(PatientRegistrationEntity patient, MultipartFile image) throws IOException {

        return patient;
    }
```

This is the controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/patient/")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowCredentials = "true")

public class PatientRegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    PatientRegistrationService registrationService;
    
    @PostMapping("post")
     public void savePatient(@ModelAttribute PatientRegistrationEntity patient, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        registrationService.createPatient(patient, image);    
    }
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum , this is the first time I am working on this type of coding. I cannot save image with other data.

Comment: And the problem is? No data being saved? Only image data not saved, an error? Please describe the problem you have in more detail. Currently there is only code and you expect us to figure out what is happening from that. This is not how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an entity class like this way:

```
@Component
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "imageTemplates")
public class ImageTemplatesClientDocuments implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "templateContract")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private byte[] templateContract;

    @Lob
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TemplateAgreement")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private byte[] templateAgreement;

    @Lob
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "templateQuestionnaire")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private byte[] templateQuestionnaire;

    @Lob
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "templateClientFoto")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private byte[] templateClientFoto;
}
```

and your images will be saved in the database as 'longblob' (for MySQL).
Since you are using the Rest API this should work (it works for me), using @ModelAttribute is possible for Spring MVC (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation)

Comment: what should I do instead of Modelattribute in springboot?

Comment: you can look at the whole code, something like this:  https://github.com/YustasDev/NewMedicalService